# What is the pressure difference between capillaries and the outside air?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, computational-physics, rheology

Why exactly do we bleed? There is a pressure gradient that causes the blood to flow from the capillaries to the outside of the skin. What is this pressure difference? The pressure inside the capillaries is at most 35 torr. The atmospheric pressure is 760 torr, which seems strange;how are we able to bleed at all. Is the gas compressible whereas blood is not and is this contributing to this phenomenon? Are my numbers wrong?

How do I work with these two values?
I'm working on a simulation where I need the pressure of the capillaries which are underneath the skin and the pressure outside the skin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your value of $35$ torr (which is sometimes called the gauge pressure) is the excess pressure over atmospheric pressure i.e. The absolute blood pressure is $760+35= 795$ torr.

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot of sense! Thank you very much!